# LibCurl Telnet write data "An unknown option was passed in"

Tags: c, ubuntu, libcurl, telnet

I have projector with option to communicate by TELNET. I want to send to him question about power on/off by this comamnd:

```
:POWR ?\r
```

My code:

```
  FILE* console = fopen("/dev/tty", "w");

  CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
  CURLcode res;

  if (curl)
  {
    CURLcode res;

    struct curl_slist* options;
    options = curl_slist_append(NULL, "TTTYPE=:POWR ?\r");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "telnet://192.168.0.90");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 1025);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TELNETOPTIONS, options);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
      fprintf(console, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(options);
    fprintf(console, s.c_str());
  }
```

As result i have:

```
curl_easy_perform() failed: An unknown option was passed in to libcurl
```

I think, that problem is with:

```
struct curl_slist* options;
options = curl_slist_append(NULL, "TTTYPE=:POWR ?\r");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TELNETOPTIONS, options);
```

But how to send data to projector and get result?

In PUTTY is ok:

[image]

Comment: What do you think that `TTTYPE=:POWR ?\r` does?

Comment: Looks more like write data than a telnet option.

Comment: @user253751 this from here: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TELNETOPTIONS.html I thin that this is data send over telnet.

Comment: Why do you think that this is data sent over telnet?

Comment: When I try bellow code, program is freeze:
`const char data[] = ":POWR ?\r";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, sizeof(data));`

Comment: I add to code: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);` and in log have:  `*   Trying 192.168.0.90:1025...
* Connected to 192.168.0.90 (192.168.0.90) port 1025 (#0)` but havet result. This is with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE`

Comment: with `TTTYPE` i have:
`*   Trying 192.168.0.90:1025...
* Connected to 192.168.0.90 (192.168.0.90) port 1025 (#0)
* Unknown telnet option TTTYPE=:POWR ?
* Closing connection 0`

Comment: Take a careful look at the manual [CURLOPT_TELNETOPTIONS](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TELNETOPTIONS.html). Telnet protocol is not supported. You have to build libcurl with the enabled telnet protocol. IMHO you don't need libcurl, just use a TCP socket.